# can't migrate the dates from firebase to my class (No setter/field warning)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I try to save of my SQLite database some records from the Firebase database.

My code to access the firebase and to store the information's in an ArrayList is:

```
private List<PoIs> LocoList;


LocoList = new ArrayList<>();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DATABASE");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            LocoList.clear();
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    PoIs loco = dataSnapshot.getValue(PoIs.class);
                    LocoList.add(loco);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The PoIs class looks like this:

```
public class PoIs {
private Integer _location_id;
private String _location_name;
private String _location_address;
private String _location_description;
private String _location_county;

public PoIs(){}

public PoIs(Integer _location_id, String _location_name, String _location_address,String _location_description, String _location_county) {
    this._location_id = _location_id;
    this._location_name = _location_name;
    this._location_address = _location_address;
    this._location_description = _location_description;
    this._location_county = _location_county;
}


@PropertyName("_location_description")
public String get_location_description() {
    return _location_description;
}

@PropertyName("_location_description")
public void set_location_description(String _location_description) {
    this._location_description = _location_description;
}
```

My firebase structure look like this:

```
{
"DATABASE": {


"PoI_100": {
"_location_address": "Comuna SÃ¢mbÄƒta ",
"_location_county": "BRASOV",
"_location_description": "N/A",
"_location_id": 100,
"_location_name": "MÄƒnÄƒstireaÂ SÃ¢mbÄƒta (BrÃ¢ncoveanu)",
},
"PoI_1000": {
"_location_address": "CostineÈ™ti ",
"_location_county": "CONSTANTA",
"_location_description": "N/A",
"_location_id": 1000,
"_location_name": "Teatrul de VarÄƒ",
},
"PoI_1001": {
"_location_address": "Olimp",
"_location_county": "CONSTANTA",
"_location_description": "N/A",
"_location_id": 1001,
"_location_image": "-",
"_location_name": "Plaja Olimp",
},

...

All are in a child node named "database".
```

Unfortunately, I get a warning like no setter/field exists for my class. Any idea?

Comment: Can you show the errors?

Comment: When are you getting `(No setter/field warning)`, when you try to read the data from Firebase? If yes, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Updated firebase json structure

Comment: @SohaibAhmed " no setter/field for PoI_861 found on class com.test.testapp.models.PoIs". and error repeat for each node of database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was here:

```
if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         ///// HERE: I used dataSnapshot instead ds
         PoIs loco = dataSnapshot.getValue(PoIs.class);
         /////
         LocoList.add(loco);
    }
}
```

Was enough to replace with

```
PoIs loco = ds.getValue(PoIs.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the following warning:

> No setter/field warning

Because the names of the fields in your class are different than the ones in the database. For example, in your class, you have a field called `location_address` while in the database is called `_location_address`. See the `_` (underscore) with which the field starts? That's the reason why you get that warning. To solve this, you either modify the names of the fields in the class to match the ones in the database, or you use an annotation in front of the public getter slike this:

```
@PropertyName("_location_address") //
public String getLocation_address() {
    return location_address;
}
```

Comment: i have added underscore to all fields starts but with same result.

Comment: Have you tried to use the annotation then? Does it work that way?

Comment: Same result. I updated the PoI class on my question,

Comment: maybe is from here .. public PoIs(){} ? but without this i get next error Class xxxxxx.PoIs does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.

Comment: My advice in your case would be not to use `_` but use the Jaba naming convention. For instance, a field in your class should be called `locationId` and not `_location_id`. The same name (`locationId`) should also exist in the database. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: the underscore was placed automatically by firebase. Just saw now that I posted wrong the json. I updated up. the corect json start with {
  "DATABASE": {
    "PoI_100": {
....  The POI are children of DATABASE node.

Comment: Just follow the Java naming convention and name your fields in the class and in the database according to it. And yes, try that and tell me if it works that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251261/discussion-between-nick-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Have you tried my advice in the last comment?

Comment: yes, with same result.